# What was the 'cricket' noise for?

Tags: plot-explanation, cell

In [Cell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0775440/)...

When the protagonists are on the outskirts of Boston they are chased by a group of phone zombies. The protagonists hide and the phone zombies do not find them, instead they all turn to face a lake and start making a type of eerie creaking 'cricket' chirp.

[image]

Why did they stop chasing the protagonists and start doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Because these cell phone zombies can communicate with each other. The phoners have a sort of hivemind, grouping into flocks and helping each other scavenge for food.

> They communicate by emitting an inhuman noise, a mixture of insectoid clicking and static. [popzara](http://www.popzara.com/movies/movie-reviews/cell-2016/)